# Pharo 8 error: PrimitiveFailed: primitive #'insufficient object memory' in File class failed

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Good day Pharo developers,

I have a problem running Pharo 8 in raspberry pi. At the startup it will prompt this error "PrimitiveFailed: primitive #'insufficient object memory' in File class failed". When I checked the sd card usage it has still 4GB remaining. During startup also I observed it only uses 26% of the process. May I know what is the root cause of this error? What procedure need to solve this issue? By the way, I am using a fresh image on this.

Best Regards,
Lester